# ER diagram for the schema where foreign keys are not mentioned

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, entity-relationship

I have a schema with 160 tables and no foreign keys were mentioned. Is there any simple way to create ER diagrams for all the tables with out manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using an IDE.  Eclipse, Jetbrains IDEA, and MS Visual Studio all have plugins for generating ER diagrams, depending on which version of what you are using.

Since you mention Oracle SQL Developer, that has a plugin for generating an ER diagram.  [Here is an example of how to do it.](https://dataedo.com/kb/tools/oracle-sql-developer/create-database-diagram).

Comment: Thanks, It creates tables without mapping because i don't have foreign keys in my tables. Do i need to map on my own  ?

Comment: If you don't have foreign keys, the database has no way of knowing that those columns are related.  So yes, the only option is to do that mapping yourself (or create some foreign keys).